# Docker :: How to see the packaging inside an image made from Docker for Mac?

Tags: docker, wildfly, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I created an image `wildfly` using **Docker Desktop for Mac**. Then I tried to run it, however, there seems to be some deployment error when the image is run.
In order to check if the docker file packaged the image properly or not, I would like to debug it by checking its content.

Is there a way to see the contents inside an image made from Docker Desktop for Mac?

Comment: Is your docker container running or fails to run?

Comment: It fails to run. Deployment error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looking at the image, it would probably be easier to start the image from a shell and introspect it via that.

`docker run -it wildfily /bin/sh`

Answer (score 1):

`docker history` shows the commands used to build the image, otherwise, you could `docker run` the image, using `sh` as the command to enter into a terminal. Then you can browse the file system as normal